# GitBash. Can't type characters

Tags: git, git-bash

I've just installed git onto my machine (Windows 7) and opened Git Bash terminal and i'm not able to type characters into it. If i press a key nothing happens. I am able however to type digits, they are seen, but not letters, except if i type letter S it outputs some huge weird set of words, not understandable to me. Also if i type letter J then i'm able to see output from pressing on letter keys but it outputs digits instead of letters. Can anyone please explain me what the hell is going on and how can i fix it?

This is the screenshot of the GitBash:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like some keymap/charset issue...maybe post a screenshot of the output from pressing S? What language is your OS and what keyboard mapping are you using? This might just be a bug in GitBash (you should report it).

Comment: See the screenshot i've added. My system's language is Russian, but i typed English letters of course

Comment: That is **weird**. It looks like Bash is printing out a list of files in your current directory, compressed using brace notation. I didn't even know that functionality existed.

Comment: Still, I'd be willing to believe it's a bug due to the language setting. Maybe try a different terminal utility like MinTTY.

Comment: @nneonneo well, how can i try a different one? The current one is default installation, so how can i change it?

Comment: https://github.com/rpavlik/git-windows-mintty, http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=29#c34.

Comment: @nneonneo i'm sorry to disturb you but i cannot launch this programm. it says that msys-1.0.dll is missing on the computer. i've downloaded this thing msys-1.0.dll and put it inside mintty folder but that didn't help. do you have any idea how make it work?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't personally have experience with MinTTY for Git; I used to just use MinTTY with Cygwin.